# How to add information to a pivot table in laravel?

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I have a many:many relation between student and course.

Here are my models and my pivot table:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'surname',
        'age',
        'tdah',
        'description',
        'hobbies',
    ];

   /*  public function course(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
    } */

    public function data(){
        return $this->hasMany(Datum::class, 'student_id', 'id');
    }

    public function configurations(){
        return $this->hasMany(Configuration::class, 'student_id', 'id');
    }

    public function courses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'course_student', 'student_id', 'course_id');
    }

}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Course extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'academic_course_id',
        'user_id',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function academicCourse()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AcademicCourse::class);
    }

    public function planification(){
        return $this->hasOne(Planification::class, 'course_id', 'id');
    }

    public function subjects(){
        return $this->hasMany(Subject::class, 'course_id', 'id');
    }

    /* public function students(){
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class, 'course_id', 'id');
    } */

    public function students(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class, 'course_student', 'course_id', 'student_id');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('course_student', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->foreignId('course_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('student_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('course_student');
    }
};
```

I'd like to create a student that belongs to a group. I know how to create a student and a group, but I'd like to create a register for that student in my course_student pivot table. My StudentController method store is:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Student::create($request->all());
        $courses = Course::all();
        $academicCourses = AcademicCourse::all();
        return view('course.index', compact('courses', 'academicCourses')); 
    }
```

It creates a new student but I don`t know how to create a new register for the pivot table.

I thought about doing something like:

```
course_student::create(request)
```

in my store method but I think it isn`t that way.

Comment: You have defined a belongstoMany relationship. on that function you can use `$student->courses()->sync([1,2])` where 1 and 2 are the ids of the courses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$student->courses()->attach($courseId);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Edit :

You can use attach() method on the relationship. In your code it would look like this :

```
public function store(Request $request, Course $course) //add parameter course to know which course needs to be attached
{
    $newStudent = Student::create($request->all()); // create() returns instance of created Student
    $newStudent->courses()->attach($course->id);
    $courses = Course::all();
    $academicCourses = AcademicCourse::all();
    return view('course.index', compact('courses', 'academicCourses')); 
}
```

Comment: always explain your answer. Not only by adding a link (it can change in the future)

Comment: Thank you @StewieSWS for your answer. I guess what that line does is creating a new register in my pívot table when I create a new student but I don’t know where I should write that line. Thank you.

Comment: @lewis04 in your store method you are taking all courses and passing it to the view. If i understand correctly, in this view you want to let the student select a course, that's correct?

Comment: @StewieSWS taking all the courses is for another thing. What I do is taking the request which is a new student and create a new register in the table student. At the same tike I’d like to create a new register in my course_student table with the new student and the course

Comment: @lewis04 Okay, but what course? All of them should be assigned to this new student?

Comment: @StewieSWS not all of them. Only one course. The method store can have another parameter which would be the  course. So the request is a new student and another parameter would be the course that student has to be assigned to.

Comment: Alright, then you need to take id of that Course, for example $course->id and put it as parameter in attach() method. I'll edit my answer to show

Comment: @StewieSWS thank you very much. I will try it and tell you how it goes.

Comment: @StewieSWS it works perfectly. That´s what I wanted. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel you can do it by using attach function, Attach() function has two parameters :

1- the another foreign key in you case **attach(course_id)**.

2-(this is optional) array for any another columns inside pivot table for example :

```
attach(course_id,['users_id'=>$usersId])
```

In your case you will create the records inside  the pivot table (**course_student**) via the object from student model .

```
$student->courses()->attach($course_id);
```

note :
there is another method which does the opposite  **detach()** but you need to use it carefully if you write it without any parameter it will remove all the records inside  (**course_student**) that belong to the student object so specify the course that you want to remove it by that way :

```
$student->courses()->detach($course_id);
```

I hope that will help you ...

Comment: Firs of all, thank you @Haro katsumi for your answer. I have a doubt. Where should I write the line: $student->courses()->attach($course_id); ? Cause I guess what it does is creating a new register in the pivot table when I create a new student, but I don’t know where I have to write it. Thank you.

Comment: After registering process for student ,@lewis04 will add the courses which he will attend to , so you will need another method that will let you add the course to the student this method will receive a parameter of the selected course or it can receive an array of all the courses  which belongs to that student . In the case of one parameter you will use   $student->courses()->attach($course_id);. and in the case of array you will need a loop to attach the student with each course in the array .

Comment: Thanks. That`s what I´ve done and it works perfectly. @haro katsumi